# Custom Lambert Conformal projection of 2D data gives very large file size when saved as pdf (16MB)

Tags: python-3.x, python-xarray, cartopy

I'm trying to save a figure to use in my thesis, but the figure becomes 16MB (The figures made from PlateCarree projections are order of 100-200kB)

I have provided the code, any tips, tricks and otherwise would be greatly appreciated.

SUM is a netcdf-file with coords len(y) = 949 and len(x) = 889

```py
projection = ccrs.LambertConformal(central_latitude=63,central_longitude=15,standard_parallels=[63,63],cutoff=-30)

fig = plt.figure(figsize = (12,10))
ax = plt.subplot(projection=projection)

SUM.plot.pcolormesh(ax=ax,cbar_kwargs = {"label":"Temperature - [C]"})

ax.set_title("Mean Temperature - 750m height")
ax.coastlines("50m")
fig.savefig(outsource+"MeanT750.pdf")
```

I have tried giving the DPI-argument to savefig, but it does not change the filesize.

Answer (score 0):

A PDF file in your case, contains vector data. You can reduce the level of details to decrease the file size. For example:

```
ax.coastlines("110m")
```

will save thousands of bytes over `50m` resolution, but still represents good visualization on the map.

For the `pcolormesh()`, the memory varies with the value `(rows*columns)` of your meshed data. If you reduce number of rows/columns, you reduce the memory.

However, if `contourf()` can be used instead of `pcolormesh()`, you may save much more.